# NodeMCU NeoPixel

Tags: led, nodemcu

I am attempting to control a single NeoPixel with a NodeMCU, but I'm not having any luck.  Even just loading the default Adafruit NeoPixel library sketch yields unsuccessful results.  I've tested the exact same sketch on a regular Arduino with sucess.  I've got the data line hooked up to D5 on the NodeMCU board and here is my configuration of the Pixel in the sketch.

```
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(1, D5, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

The  node mcu is an esp8xxx with 3.3V outputs.

The neopixel is an ws2812 led controller that normally uses 5V logic.

They cannot communicate. This is why it's failing.

Lower the voltage used for the neopixel so that 3.3V is within 70% of the neopixel VIN or use a logic level translator.

Comment: I added a logic shifter, but I'm still not getting any response from the Pixel.

Comment: Schematic please.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/QTG1a

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It were resolved by initializing the pin as OUTPUT:

```
  pinMode(PIN, OUTPUT);
  pixels.begin(); // This initializes the NeoPixel library.
```

As I understand Arduino bootloader does it by itself but bootloader of ESP8266 does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a LoLin NodeMCU board while it worked with the Amica NodeMCU board.

When powered via USB, the Amica board provided 5V on the `Vin` pin, but the LoLin board didn't. I had to use the `VU` pin instead and it worked.

I did not need a logic shifter. I used the D2 pin with a 220 Ohm resistor for the data.